# Cmake is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: github, cmake, command-prompt, openpose

I have to download all the things from this link

```
https://github.com/adujardin/zed-openpose
```

I download the openpose file, and I put in its examples/user_code/  the zed-openpose file that i downloaded
I get stuck in the installation process

```
cd openpose
mkdir build
cmake .. # This can take a while
make -j8
sudo make install
```

When I type cmake , it gives me the Error in the title: WHY?

Comment: You need to install `cmake` before being able to use it. A package containing `cmake` executable usually is named `cmake`.

Comment: I already have cmake, but I will delete it and reinstall it just to be sure everything is ok